# Cpanel requiring MySQL upgrade, yet cpanel package is up to date?

Tags: centos, mysql

I'm running CentOS; WHM/CPanel is telling me:

> fatal: Newer releases of cPanel & WHM are not compatible with your MySQL version: 5.0. Upgrade your MySQL server to a version greater or equal to 5.1

I checked my version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.96, for pc-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.1
```

So I checked my installed package via yum:

```
Installed Packages    

cpanel-mysql.i386            5.0.96-1.cp1136         installed
```

It looks up to date. I feel like I'm stuck in a loop here, how am I suppose to upgrade WHM while staying within CPanel's packages?

Attempting to update:

```
yum update cpanel-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.beyondhosting.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.teklinks.com
 * updates: ftp.usf.edu
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Comment: 5.0.96 is definitely less than 5.1.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes I already realize this, but it's the package supplied by CPanel and yum is not saying there's a newer version available (as in I'm up to date for MySQL).

Comment: What did cPanel support tell you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @HopelessN00b What SE site can I ask this on?

Comment: @Zeno webmasters might be appropriate... check around first, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use YUM. CPanel will block mysql and other common services as it takes control over the server. You have to use the upgrade option in WHM :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily upgrade your server’s MySQL version with WHM’s “MySQL Upgrade” interface, which is located at: Home >> Software >> MySQL Upgrade.